# result of ofTrueTypeFont.drawString() seems to be with large spaces

Tags: c++, openframeworks

As I notice the result of such code:

```
ofTrueTypeFont lttf;
lttf.loadFont("segoeuil.ttf", 48);
lttf.drawString("aruku around", 50, 350);
```

It seems that the space between "aruku" and "around" is a wide character ("　") space, not the regular half character (" ") one, as in this question.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks normal to me.  The pitch of a space is normally the same as the pitch of the digits.  Which are kinda big for Segoe.  Pick another font if you don't like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
[setSpaceSize (...)](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofTrueTypeFont.html#setSpaceSize)
Maybe you will be able adjust space size with this.